# Fill the tail of a literal with all 0's SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, literals

I am very new to SystemVerilog. I wanted to use quite a long literal as a mask. This literal, is supossed to be 18 bytes long and the only relevant part is on the most significant bytes, as the 14 least significant bytes need to be all 0's. Writing `'h00000FFC00000000000000000000000000` is quite tedious. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streaming operator left justifies to the most significant bits.

```
dest = {>>{32'h0000_0FFC}};
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be easily fixed using concatenation. For the example I showed in the question, it would be like this:

`{32'h0000_0FFC, 112'b0}`